# Make outputs single ended on CS4234

Tags: audio, differential, single-ended, stereo, cirrus

I am working with the [CS4234 codec](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4234_F1.pdf) for a project
It has 4 ADCs and 5DACs.  One thing that is confusing me is that the pins are labled AOUT1- and AOUT1+ in the similar fashion for all ADCs and DACs.

The device states it can do single ended, which I believe is what I need to achieve stereo sound.  How can I change these various ADCs and DACs to Left and Right input/output channels?

Could I just use the positive for left and then the negative for right? Like are they already in this configuration or do I need to use an op-amp to convert the signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The device states it can do single ended, which I believe is what I need to achieve stereo sound.

No.  Single ended would just be using AOUT1+ and ignoring AOUT1-, or combining both + and - into a single signal with an op-amp.  For stereo you would use AOUT1 *and* AOUT2 in either single-ended or differential mode.

Using an op-amp to make a differential output into single ended can be done like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fED9RR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>